# Print only the name of variable with the class factor

Tags: r

I have the data set in which some are factors as well some are numerical/integer, so what should be the command to return only the name of factor class.

```
aa bb cc dd
1  12 P  43
4  23 Q  78
8  34 Q  89
9  86 P  78
7  67 P  98
9  76 Q  74
```

So, now if I want to print only the name of variable with the class factor, i.e. cc, so what should be my R command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
names(Filter(is.factor, data))
```

This also is a little longer but might be using less memory:

```
names(data)[sapply(data, is.factor)]
```

Comment: Probably best to use `vapply` instead of `sapply` there, i.e., `names(data)[vapply(data, is.factor, logical(1))]`

Comment: @MichaelLawrence: `is.factor` always return a `logical(1)` so there is no robustness concern here. The only left benefit of `vapply` is a marginal speed improvement, unlikely to make any difference here (data.frames rarely have thousands of columns.) So this is actually one situation where I prefer `sapply` over `vapply`, for its conciseness. (And this is coming from a `vapply` fan)

Comment: But if there are zero columns, `sapply` returns `list()`, not `logical()`, which sort of bothers me. Also, just personal preference, but there is an advantage to being explicit about the type, in terms of code clarity. Obviously the priorities will depend on interactive use vs. software.

Comment: Nice catch about the zero case. I'll keep that in mind.